# FabricJS - Continues rotation on object rotation event

Tags: canvas, rotation, fabricjs

I'm experiencing weird behavior of an element when using **object:rotating** event function. The element continuously rotates with some extra angle. Looks like the angle accumulates all the time to the previous angle...

Basically, what I try to achieve is a proper position and angle of the YELLOW element when rotating a red one.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/gjq7gmt9/14/).Please try to rotate the red element.

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper',{
                preserveObjectStacking: true
            });

const data = {
    red:{
     top: 50,
        left: 50,
        angle: -30,
        width: 300,
        height: 200
    },
 yellow:{
     top: 50,
        left: 50,
        angle: 20,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    }
};
const yellow = new fabric.Rect({
    left: data.yellow.left, 
    top:  data.yellow.top,
    fill: 'yellow',
    angle:  data.yellow.angle,
    width: data.yellow.width,
    height: data.yellow.height,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    opacity: .7
});

yellow.setPositionByOrigin({x:yellow.getLeft() + yellow.getWidth() / 2, y: yellow.getTop() + yellow.getHeight() / 2}, 'center', 'center');

fabric.Image.fromURL('//images.sftcdn.net/images/t_optimized,f_auto/p/85e6f558-9a68-11e6-bdf1-00163ed833e7/1312338326/slack-logo.png', function(img) {
    const patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
    patternSourceCanvas.enableRetinaScaling = false;
    patternSourceCanvas.setBackgroundColor('red', patternSourceCanvas.renderAll.bind(patternSourceCanvas));
    patternSourceCanvas.setBackgroundImage(img, patternSourceCanvas.renderAll.bind(patternSourceCanvas), {
        top: yellow.getTop() - yellow.getWidth() / 2,
        left: yellow.getLeft() - yellow.getHeight() / 2,
        width: yellow.getWidth(),
        height: yellow.getHeight(),
        angle: yellow.getAngle(),
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
    });

    var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
        source: function() {
            patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
                width: data.red.width,
                height: data.red.height
            });
            patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
            return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
        },
        repeat: 'no-repeat'
    });

    const red = new fabric.Rect({
        left: data.red.left,
        top: data.red.top,
        angle: data.red.angle,
        fill: pattern,
        width: data.red.width,
        height: data.red.height,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        patternSourceCanvas: patternSourceCanvas
    });
 red.setPositionByOrigin({x:red.getLeft() + red.getWidth() / 2, y: red.getTop() + red.getHeight() / 2}, 'center', 'center');
    
    canvas.add(red);
    canvas.add(yellow);
   
    canvas.on('object:rendered', function(){
  console.log('Rednder')
    });
    
    red.on('rotating', function(){
     updateYellowPosition();
    });
    red.on('moving', function(){
     updateYellowPosition();
    });
   
    updateYellowPosition();
   
   
    function updateYellowPosition(){
     // Here I would like to have some logic which will identify proper position
        // (left, top and angle) of Red's background image location and apply those 
        // to the Yellow element
        console.log('Yellow left top', red, red.angle, red.getAngle(), yellow.getLeft(), yellow.getTop());
        const shiftX = red.patternSourceCanvas.backgroundImage.left;
        const shiftY = red.patternSourceCanvas.backgroundImage.top;
        const backgroundAngle = red.patternSourceCanvas.backgroundImage.angle;
        const redCenterPoint = red.getCenterPoint();
        const newYellowPos = fabric.util.rotatePoint(
            new fabric.Point( 
             yellow.getLeft(), 
    yellow.getTop()
            ), // NOT SURE
            new fabric.Point(
             redCenterPoint.x, 
                redCenterPoint.y
            ), // NOT SURE
            fabric.util.degreesToRadians(red.getAngle())  // NOT SURE
        );  
        
        yellow.setPositionByOrigin (
         {
             x: newYellowPos.x,
             y: newYellowPos.y
         },
            'center',
            'center'
        );

        yellow.rotate(yellow.getAngle() + red.getAngle()).setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }

},{crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is there any problem, if you make them a group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example shows you how to handle transform in a generic way in fabricJS.

You should find the relative position from the center of the red rectangle.
save it in a variable.

Each transform step, calculate the red rect transform matrix, and use that matrix to figure out where in the canvas is now that relative position.

position the yellow rectangle there and give it the right angle.

I updated the example to work with scaleX and scaleY too.

It should work aslo with skewing if you would ever need it.

Matrix can transform all that the 2d canvas can do, so you should learn how to use them, they often offer the solution and a code shortcut

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper',{
                preserveObjectStacking: true
            });

const data = {
    red:{
     top: 50,
        left: 50,
        angle: -30,
        width: 300,
        height: 200
    },
 yellow:{
     top: 50,
        left: 50,
        angle: 20,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    }
};
const yellow = new fabric.Rect({
    left: data.yellow.left, 
    top:  data.yellow.top,
    fill: 'yellow',
    angle:  data.yellow.angle,
    width: data.yellow.width,
    height: data.yellow.height,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    opacity: .7
});

yellow.setPositionByOrigin({x:yellow.getLeft() + yellow.getWidth() / 2, y: yellow.getTop() + yellow.getHeight() / 2}, 'center', 'center');

fabric.Image.fromURL('//images.sftcdn.net/images/t_optimized,f_auto/p/85e6f558-9a68-11e6-bdf1-00163ed833e7/1312338326/slack-logo.png', function(img) {
    const patternSourceCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas();
    patternSourceCanvas.enableRetinaScaling = false;
    patternSourceCanvas.setBackgroundColor('red', patternSourceCanvas.renderAll.bind(patternSourceCanvas));
    patternSourceCanvas.setBackgroundImage(img, patternSourceCanvas.renderAll.bind(patternSourceCanvas), {
        top: yellow.getTop() - yellow.getWidth() / 2,
        left: yellow.getLeft() - yellow.getHeight() / 2,
        width: yellow.getWidth(),
        height: yellow.getHeight(),
        angle: yellow.getAngle(),
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
    });

    var pattern = new fabric.Pattern({
        source: function() {
            patternSourceCanvas.setDimensions({
                width: data.red.width,
                height: data.red.height
            });
            patternSourceCanvas.renderAll();
            return patternSourceCanvas.getElement();
        },
        repeat: 'no-repeat'
    });

    const red = new fabric.Rect({
        left: data.red.left,
        top: data.red.top,
        angle: data.red.angle,
        fill: pattern,
        width: data.red.width,
        height: data.red.height,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        patternSourceCanvas: patternSourceCanvas
    });
 red.setPositionByOrigin({x:red.getLeft() + red.getWidth() / 2, y: red.getTop() + red.getHeight() / 2}, 'center', 'center');
  
  // you are working with center coordinates
// find the distance between the 2 centers and the angle difference.
var angleDiff = yellow.angle; // the image to cover is angled as yellow angle, relative to red angle
var centerDiff = yellow.getCenterPoint().subtract(red.getCenterPoint());
    
    canvas.add(red);
    canvas.add(yellow);
   
    canvas.on('object:rendered', function(){
  console.log('Rednder')
    });
    
    red.on('rotating', function(){
     updateYellowPosition();
    });
    red.on('moving', function(){
     updateYellowPosition();
    });
    red.on('scaling', function(){
     updateYellowPosition();
    });
   
    updateYellowPosition();
   
   
    function updateYellowPosition(){
     // Here I would like to have some logic which will identify proper position
        // (left, top and angle) of Red's background image location and apply those 
        // to the Yellow element
        var matrix = red.calcTransformMatrix(); // get all the position information of red
        var newCenterForYellow = fabric.util.transformPoint(centerDiff, matrix);
        yellow.top = newCenterForYellow.y;
        yellow.left = newCenterForYellow.x;
        yellow.angle = red.angle + angleDiff;
         yellow.scaleX = red.scaleX;
         yellow.scaleY = red.scaleY;
        canvas.renderAll();
    }

},{crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'});
```

```css
canvas {

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you, Andrea. Working good!
I need a bit different behavior with the Scaling, but it's good enough for the start... Basically, for scaling of the red, I need to change its height and width but leave scaling 1 all the time, so kind of resizing instead of scaling... 
Do you think your code may support that kind of behavior?

Comment: I've checked scaling... doesn't work properly... try to scale red, for example,  vertically and you'll notice that yellow gets the wrong transformation.

Comment: yes if you scale from one side you have to to add skew support i guess. a bit more code.

Comment: tnx. One more question... will you be able to help me now with the yellow one too? Now I need to move a YELLOW element and apply proper position on the RED's pattern... 
Could you please help me with that? you so good with all those functions of transformation :)

Comment: @EugeneVilder if you want to move, relative to each other. Make a group of all the object.

Comment: Grouping is not an option for me; I need those be separate.
But thank you for the suggestion.